# If value is null put an empty string on razor template?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a razor template like below. I want to check if the value in the input field is null, put a empty string, if the `@UIManager.Member.EMail` has a value, put its value. How can I do that?

Normal Input:

```html
<input name="EMail" id="SignUpEMail" type="text" class="Input" 
       value="@UIManager.Member.EMail" validate="RequiredField" />
```

Razor Syntax Attempt:

```html
<input name="EMail" id="SignUpEMail" type="text" class="Input" validate="RequiredField"
       value="@(UIManager.Member == null) ? string.Empty : UIManager.Member.EMail" />
```

The value is shown in the input field is:

```
True ? string.Empty : UIBusinessManager.MemberCandidate.EMail
```

Comment: as long as UIManager and UIManager.Member are non-null, this should already work... can you clarify?

Comment: Actually @UIManager.Member is initially  null. It gets its value after a postback operation. So it doesnt work, you're right. How to check it so ?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

If sounds like you just want:

```
@(UIManager.Member == null ? "" : UIManager.Member.Email)
```

Note the locations of the brackets is critical; with razor, `@(....)` defines an *explicit* range to the code - hence anything *outside* the brackets is treated as markup (not code).

Answer (score 27):

This is exactly what the `NullDisplayText` property on [`[DisplayFormat]` attribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayformatattribute.aspx) is for.

Add this directly on your model:

```cs
[DisplayFormat(NullDisplayText="", ApplyFormatInEditMode=true)]
public string EMail { get; set; }
```

Comment: I believe this is the best answer If an approach is considered. Much cleaner and easier to implement.

Comment: +1 Note: I've found it necessary to do `@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Email)` since that attribute gets ignored by `@Model.Email`.

Answer (score 21):

To Check some property of a model in cshtml.

```
@if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.CUSTOM_PROPERTY))
{
    <p>@Model.CUSTOM_PROPERTY</p>
}
else
{
    <p> - </p>
}
```

so best way to do this:

```
@(Model.CUSTOM_PROPERTY ?? "-")
```

Comment: So glad we can do that now, like in JS.

Answer (score 3):

Use the [null conditional operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986595(v=vs.140).aspx):

```
@UIManager.Member?.Email
```

Comment: It should be @(UIManager.Member?.Email)

Comment: To answer the question it should be: @(UIManager.Member?.Email ?? string.Empty)

Answer (score 0):

```
$" ({UIManager.Member.FirstOrDefault()?.EMail})" ?? "N/A"
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).