# Set string to empty if no version number exists in Razor HTML

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am building a simple structure in cshtml: if no version number exists, set string to empty, otherwise place a link with version info

```
<label style="float:right;">
    Version: @resp.VersionNumber
    @if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(@resp.VersionNumber))
    {
         @resp.VersionNumber == "";
    }
    else
    {
         <a>Version link code</a>
    }
</label>
```

Resp is JsonResponce local variable, while VersionNumber is a string Datamember of JsonResponce class.

While it looks extremely easy, it was returning errors that made me scratch my head.

The error is inside the if statement. I tried encasing the line in the () like was suggested by accepted answer in [that thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7089725/if-value-is-null-put-an-empty-string-on-razor-template), but it was returning a compilation error, like in [that post](http://forums.asp.net/t/1704881.aspx?Razor+syntax+for+inline+IF+statement+checking+for+variable+in+list). Structures in both cases are a bit different than mine, so I cannot exactly apply those.

If I leave the line inside if as is, it was returning compilation errors of `invalid expression term ==` and `expected ;` , even though I already have it.

*I understand that I am probably missing something simple, but can you please point me to how I should change my code in order to remove those errors. And briefly explain why it is doing this, since I want to learn from this question as well.*

I am a beginner self-learner in that area, so please go easy on me. Thank you very much!

## UPDATE

Based on everyones's proposed suggestions, I rearranged my code, and now it looks like the following

```
<label style="float:right;">
     Version: 
     @if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(resp.VersionNumber))
     {
         <span></span>;
     }
         else
     {
         @resp.VersionNumber
         <a>Version link code</a>
     }
</label>
```

Comment: `=` is for assigning a value, `==` is for comparing values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several errors. First you have @ in places where it doesn't belong, since you're already in a code block. You use comparison (==) when you most likely want assignment(=). You also first output the value and then want to modify it.

Most likely you are after something like this

```
<label style="float:right;">
  Version:
  @if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(resp.VersionNumber))
  {
    <span>No version number!</span>
  } else {
    <a>Version link code</a>
  }
</label>
```

This way you check if it exists, if not you just output a text and if it does you do the link how you want.

Comment: Your answer was the closest to give me the desired result. I'll edit my post and accept your answer once limit is over.

Comment: Also, can you please briefly explain this whole @ misplacement or point me to some good sources to it?

Comment: @VadzimSavenok @ starts a code block, so you only use it for that. You don't need it in the middle of the code ever. Good starting point http://www.asp.net/web-pages/overview/getting-started/introducing-razor-syntax-c

Comment: Thank you, I will definitely look into it!

Answer (score 0):

This

```
 @resp.VersionNumber == "No version number!";
```

should be

```
 @resp.VersionNumber = "No version number!";
```

You use == to compare values, use = to assign values:

Assignment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbkb459w.aspx
Equality: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53k8ybth.aspx

Comment: I just tried it, it was returning same 2 errors, except it was `invalid expression term =`

Answer (score 0):

This will only show the version related info if a version number exists

```
<label style="float:right;">
    @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(resp.VersionNumber)) {
        Version: @Html.ActionLink(resp.VersionNumber, "actionName", "controllerName")
    }
</label>
```